# How CSRF attack can occur with missing State parameter and existence of PKCE is OAuth 2.0 flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, state, pkce

Imagine a situation that the client doesn't provide `state` parameter but is using `PKCE` method.

How CSRF attack can be performed?

Is there any need for the `state` parameter if the client is using `PKCE`?

I read https://security.stackexchange.com/a/215027 but it didn't provide a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **state** parameter, is something that the client validates and unfortunately, not every client implementation validates the state parameter properly. So it is a risk letting the clients be responsible for this.

**PKCE** is validated by the authorization server and probably they do a better job of verifying this than letting the clients do it.

So I think they both compliment each other, so if one of the parties involved forgets to validate, then the other protection will still cover it.

I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:

- [Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/)

Answer (score 1):

They serve a bit different purpose. PKCE is a mechanism which allows the Authorization Server to make sure that the client which exchanges authorization code for a token is the same client that initiated the flow.

The state parameter is only used by the client. Authorization server doesn't care for it. It is used by the client to verify that the token response it gets from the Authorization Server was indeed initialized by this client earlier.

So, if the client uses PKCE but doesn't use state, it protects itself only from some vectors of attacks. It's best that these features are used together.

Comment: ``` it protects itself only from some vectors of attacks ```. My question is about what exactly are others attacks that can occur if the state parameter is missing??

Comment: Have a look at this section of the OAuth spec: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-10.12 as it explains the type of attack which you can prevent with state.

Comment: Neither of the attacks mentioned there, not addressed any attacks that can happen if PKCE exists and the state parameter is missing. So I think Tore Nestenius is right.